# How to get selected JRadioButtonMenuItem in a JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jmenu

I have a `JMenu` called Options which contains a menu called `chooseColor`. The `chooseColor` menu has 7 `JRadioButtonMenuItem` (`rbtn`) to change the background color and they belong to a `JButtonGroup` (`btnGr`).

How to get the selected `rbtn`? I tried many events (`stateChanged`, `itemStateChanged`..)  of the `chooseColor` and `btnGr` but none of them work.

Is there anything like `getItemSelectedIndex`?

Comment: Use [`addActionListener(ActionListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)).

Comment: For every `rbtn` right? Thanks alot (for the advice and the edit too)
I'll give you the result ASAP

Comment: I've done it by using `getMenuComponents()` and casting them to `JRadioButtonMenuItem` then `addActionListener` 
Thank you.